# Pear Log MDB2 message length and errors

Tags: php, logging, mysqli, pear, mdb2

I recently set up a SQL logging framework with PEAR, and everything was working fine.

However, I thought that the default length of the message field (`VARCHAR 200`) was a little short, so I changed my database structure in phpmyadmin to increase this to `512`.

However, I quickly realized that this change completely stopped logging from working. I quickly changed the length back to `200`. However, even after this change, logging is still broken. I have traced the error to the log function, but unfortunately it does not give me a specific reason why it fails.

So, my question is twofold:

1. Has anyone run into this problem or something similar when using PEAR logging?
2. What is the correct way to create a longer message field?

Answer (score 0):

I found that deleting the old database and creating a new one (even with a longer message field) worked fine. Obviously not a good solution if you have lots of persistent log data that you want to keep. If anyone has any insight as to what could have been going on I would love to hear it.